# Script working with IDLE but not PowerShell

Tags: python, nltk, attributeerror

I've got this issue where this piece of code:

```
import nltk

sentence = "Hello everyone on stackoverflow!"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

print tokens
```

Throws me this kind of error, when ran from within PowerShell:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tokenize.py", line 1, in <module>
        import nltk
      File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
        from collocations import *
      File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 37, in <module>
        from nltk.util import ingrams
      File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py", line 12, in <module>
        import pydoc
      File "C:\PYTHON27\LIB\pydoc.py", line 55, in <module>
        import sys, imp, os, re, types, inspect, __builtin__, pkgutil, warnings
      File "C:\PYTHON27\LIB\inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
        import tokenize
      File "C:\stuff\tokenize.py", line 4, in <module>
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
      AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'word_tokenize'
```

But the same code has no issues in IDLE:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = "Hello everyone on stackoverflow!"
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> print tokens
['Hello', 'everyone', 'on', 'stackoverflow', '!']
>>>
```

I can't seem to get it fixed no matter what I do. At first, I thought it's the " " space in the directory so I changed it to "stuff", reinstalled nltk but the problem still persisted.

I'd appreciate some help :)

Comment: could you please do the following: `print nltk.__path__` in both the idle and powershell. It seems like it might be referencing different modules. So let's exclude that first.

Comment: PS:['C:\\PYTHON27\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk']
['C:\\PYTHON27\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk'] ///////                            IDLE:['C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly read you stack trace, you called your script `tokenize.py`. But `tokenize` is allready a module of the Standard Python Library. And still accordingly to the stack trace, the `tokenize` module is called indirectly from `nltk`. But as you have a `tokenize.py` in your current directory Python takes it instead of the standard one.

You should rename your script to a name that does not conflict with the Standard Python Library.

Comment: Thank you! :) I feel so dumb.